# React application cannot load localhost:3000

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Hi last Friday I was developing my react application which worked perfectly.However today I have come back and have tried to start it up again but it is just stuck loading the page(staying blank but showing the blue circle loading within the tab) or eventually will say that the page cannot be reached.

This is what is displayed. There is no error messages received apart from.
[image]
[image]

What could be causing this ? How could I fix this ?

I have tried opening in incognito, Refreshing and terminating and starting again.

Any suggestions are welcome. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This problem could have almost 1million reasons... You even did not provided any error message, so we´re unable to help here

Comment: When you start your app from CLI are there any issues reported there?

Comment: nope none. The page just loads for ages and then nothing happens

Comment: does it run in production mode?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by production mode. I am running  locally along with my server which is on port 5000

Comment: delete the previous node module folder. and run npm i again and thn. Thr could be infinite reason for the same .  check your local history for the same. Also You could check if there is anything running on the same port. or may be change your port and try again

Answer (score 1):

Deleted node modules and ran npm init and seemed to fix issue.